# How can I find all substrings that have this pattern: some_word.some_other_word with python?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am trying to clean up some very noisy user-generated web data.  Some people do not add a space after a period that ends the sentence.  For example,

"Place order.Call us if you have any questions."

I want to extract each sentence, but when I try to parse a sentence using nltk, it fails to recognize that these are two separate sentences. I would like to use regular expressions to find all patterns that contain "some_word.some_other_word" and all patterns that contain "some_word:some_other_word" using python.

At the same time I want to avoid finding patterns like "U.S.A".  so avoid just_a_character.just_another_character

Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some cases that might be in your text:

```
sample = """
   Place order.Call us (period: split)  
   ever after.(The end) (period: split)  
   U.S.A.(abbreviation: don't split internally)
   1.3 How to work with computers (dotted numeral: don't split)  
   ever after...The end (ellipsis: don't split internally)
   (This is the end.)   (period inside parens: don't split)  
   """
```

So: Don't add space to periods after digits, after a single capital letter, or before a paren or another period. Add space otherwise. This will do all that:

```
sample = re.sub(r"(\w[A-Z]|[a-z.])\.([^.)\s])", r"\1. \2", sample)
```

Result:

```
Place order. Call us (period: split)  
ever after. (The end) (period: split)  
U.S.A.(abbreviation: don't split internally)
1.3 How to work with computers (dotted numeral: don't split)  
ever after... The end (ellipsis: don't split internally)
(This is the end.)   (period inside parens: don't split)
```

This fixed every problem in the sample except the last period after `U.S.A.`, which *should* have a space added after it. I left that aside because combinations of conditions are tricky. The following regexp will handle everything, but **I do not recommend it:**

```
   sample = re.sub(r"(\w[A-Z]|[a-z.]|\b[A-Z](?!\.[A-Z]))\.([^.)\s])", r"\1. \2", sample)
```

Complex regexps like this are a maintainability nightmare-- just try adding another pattern, or restricting it to omit some more cases. Instead, I recommend using a separate regexp to catch just the missing case: a period after a single capital letter, but not followed by a single capital, paren, or another period.

```
sample = re.sub(r"(\b[A-Z]\.)([^.)A-Z])", r"\1 \2", sample)
```

For a complex task like this, it makes sense to use a separate regexp for each type of replacement. I'd split the original into subcases, each of which adds spaces only for a very specific pattern. You can have as many as you want, and it won't get out of hand (at least, not too much...)

Comment: Thanks so much for your post!  This really helped me out!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([.:])([^\s])', r'\1 \2', 'This is a test. Yes, test.Hello:world.')
'This is a test. Yes, test. Hello: world.'
```

The first argument — the pattern — tells that we want to match a period *or* a colon followed by a *non-whitespace* character. The second argument is the replacement, it puts the first matched symbol, then a space, then the second matched symbol back.

Comment: This will match in `this... and that`. You must check both sides of the period.

Comment: @alexis This will also match `stackoverflow.com`, `$4.5`, `text[i:i+5]` and many other unwanted substrings. I hope the OP realises, that solutions using regexes are unavoidably too straightforward and it’s impossible to do this perfectly without any real NLP. Unfortunately, afaik, NLTK can’t do this (yet).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are asking two different questions:

1) If you want to find all patterns like "some_word.some_other_word" or "some_word:some_other_word"

```
import re
re.findall('\w+[\.:\?\!]\w+', your_text)
```

This finds all patterns in the text `your_text`

2) If you want to extract all sentences, you could do

```
import re
re.split('[\.\!\?]', your_text)
```

This should return a list of sentences. For example,

```
text = 'Hey, this is a test. How are you?Fine, thanks.'
import re
re.findall('\w+[\.:\?\!]\w+', text) # returns ['you?Fine']
re.split('[\.\!\?]', text) # returns ['Hey, this is a test', ' How are you', 'Fine, thanks', '']
```

Comment: From the question it seems that the OP is going to use `nltk` to split sentences, which is, of course, way way better than just splitting on relevant punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
import re
test = "some_word.some_other_word"
r = re.compile(r'(\D+)\.(\D+)')
print r.match(test).groups()
```